# How to successfully install itunes on ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: playonlinux

I have been attempting to install itunes via Playon Linux. It installed... sort of...

I can open and view itunes, but do get the message *itunes was not properly installed* and on package manager it says the following:

```
E: Type ‘<!DOCTYPE’ is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
Go to the repository dialogue to correct the problem.
E: _cache->open() failed, please report.
```

It also does not see my iphone when connecting it to the pc.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 3):

Sadly iTunes is very proprietary and tends to break with each update after you've just managed to get it to play nicely with Wine or PlayOnLinux. Until they bring out a native Linux version, you're just going to be hurting all the time.

Give some serious consideration to dumping iTunes for music and install Google Music to listen to and buy from instead. You can copy all your existing iTunes music into your Google Account and then stream/copy it to your iPhone via the Google Music app.

Comment: I go for spotify! You can get it free, and there is a spotify for linux preview!